# App closes after capturing image and images aren't getting stored to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working on an app that uses firebase authentication to sign in users through phone numbers. After signing them in, the camera opens and the user can capture a photo that gets stored to firebase. However, the moment I capture a photo and hit ok the app closes. There are a lot of similar questions on the internet, and I have tried to work through each of them, but nothing fixes my problem. Please suggest a fix here.

This is the code of Activity.java :

```
    private Button tapCameraBtn;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private StorageReference storageReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contact);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //referencing the storage directory
        tapCameraBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tapCameraBtn);

        tapCameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!= null){

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            //creating another storage reference for filepath
            StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

            //uploading image captuured to firebase
            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Toast.makeText(AddContactActivity.this, "Uploading finished!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });


        }

    }
}
```

Manifest file is here:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AuthActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".APIActivity" android:parentActivityName=".GestureActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".GestureActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".AddContactActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

Also, I have allowed permissions for camera in my device.

A little update here, this app is now running but on a device with API 21, but when I tried running the same app on three other devices of API above 21, it is giving me the errors mentioned below:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.pooja.auxilio, PID: 17109
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.pooja.auxilio/com.example.pooja.auxilio.AddContactActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri cannot be null
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4173)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4216)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1590)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri cannot be null
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkArgument(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.example.pooja.auxilio.AddContactActivity.onActivityResult(AddContactActivity.java:104)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7111)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4169)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4216) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1590) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace of the error you are getting?

Comment: @DiegoMalone this was shown: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.pooja.auxilio/com.example.pooja.auxilio.AddContactActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference

Comment: what are these other question links can you post them, as your code looks ok

Comment: Can you debug and  share the pic path from URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way out to this:

Instead of using :

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

Use:

```
 Uri uri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
```

and include this function in your code:

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), 
    inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use that Permission than try once
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`